# Trying to automate a loop for garch estimation

Tags: r, loops

I am working with the function `ugarchfit` (package: rugarch). 
I made a script in order to estimate different garch models but sometimes the model does not converge.

My script is the following:

```
#bdd contains 5 exogeneous variables
for(i in 1:5)
 {
  specification<-ugarchspec(variance.model=list(garchOrder=c(1,1)), mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(1,1), external.regressors=bdd[,i])
  fitting<-ugarchfit(specification, out.sample=0)
 }
```

I would like that my loop does not stop when there is a convergence problem but continues to the next index.

Comment: See `?try` or `?tryCatch`.

Comment: I tried to use the function try but the loop stopped.for(i in 1:5)
 {
  specification<-ugarchspec(variance.model=list(garchOrder=c(1,1)), mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(1,1), external.regressors=bdd[,i])
  fitting<-try(ugarchfit(specification, out.sample=0)) if(inherits(fitting, "try-error") next
 }

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, but you are going to have to write the logic to handle other sorts of errors:

```
for(i in 1:5)
{
  specification <- suppressWarnings(
                     tryCatch(
                       ugarchspec(variance.model=list(garchOrder=c(1,1)), 
                                  mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(1,1), external.regressors=bdd[,i]))
                       error = function(x) return(NA))
  )
  fitting <- suppressWarnings(
    tryCatch(
      ugarchfit(specification, out.sample=0)
      error = function(x) return(NA))
  )
}
```

Comment: @Anais, did this answer your question or were you looking for something different?